# Matching and extracting data in string

Tags: java, variables, input, irc

Can someone help me (and change the title, I couldn't think of one)? I need to look for a command with Pircbot and I need it to be able to read a command like this:

```
!online user
```

And I need to do it with this:

```
something.equalsIgnoreCase("online");
```

I have no idea how to do it with it being able to read *user* with that and possibly export it to a variable? Can anyone help?

Sorry if it's really confusing.

Comment: somehow question is not clear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class in java.

Comment: I knew it was something easy that I was missing. I'm new to Java. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Heh, this was when I was very new to java. I could just use args[i]

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for a regular expression pattern.

Do something like

```
Pattern onlinePattern = Pattern.compile("online\\s(\\S)+(\\s|$)");
Matcher m = onlinePattern.matcher(stringToTest);
if (m.find()){
  String username = m.group(1);
  //... do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this is in the main class, args[] did it for me! Thanks.